# Error NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *
x = np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=6)
print(x)


"C:\Users\Piistasyo\PycharmProjects\test project\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Piistasyo/PycharmProjects/test project/loop.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Piistasyo/PycharmProjects/test project/loop.py", line 44, in <module>
    x = np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=6)
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

why am i getting this error? pls help i already installed the numpy package

Comment: change `from numpy import *` to `import numpy as np`

Comment: what if im going to use this "from numpy import * "? what should i change in my synthax?

Comment: @Piistasyo Second example of mine :-)

Comment: @Piistasyo you should never use `from numpy import *`, starred imports are considered bad

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As @aydow says, "change `from numpy import *` to `import numpy as np`":

```
import numpy as np
...
```

Or don't write `np`:

```
from numpy import *
x = random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=6)
...
```

Because, `from numpy import *`, Import every function in numpy, so `np` is not a function of numpy, so have to Import numpy like `import numpy as np`, Or, Remove `np` part of `np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=6)`, and make it like this: `random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=6)`, it's all since `random` is a function of numpy, basically that's all, to explain

Comment: It is working!!!

Answer (score 7):

You haven't defined `np`.

The first thing you're currently doing is

```
from numpy import *
```

This imports the package `numpy`, and everything inside of that package. However, numpy does not contain a module called `np`. The typical practice for numpy is to *instead* do

```
import numpy as np
```

This imports *just* the package `numpy`, and renames it to `np` so that you can dereference it by using the dot operator on `np`. This allows you to call `np.random()`, since `random` is a member of `numpy`, which is aliased to `np`.

With what you're currently doing, you could do either `numpy.random()` or just `random` (since it was part of the `*` that you imported from numpy).