# "NameError: name 'np' is not defined" when trying to run a Keras segmentation model called PspNet

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras, image-segmentation

The thing is as follows: After installing all the packages and dependencies. I've ran the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import exit
from sys import argv,exit
from keras import optimizers
from keras import backend as K
import keras_segmentation
```

And everything was OK. But, then I ran:

```
model = keras_segmentation.models.pspnet.vgg_pspnet(n_classes = 4)
```

And got this error:

```
2019-11-13 19:01:15.403630: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "semantic_sg.py", line 27, in <module>
    model = keras_segmentation.models.pspnet.vgg_pspnet(n_classes = 4)
  File "C:\Users\rodgu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras_segmentation\models\pspnet.py", line 91, in vgg_pspnet
    model =  _pspnet( n_classes , get_vgg_encoder ,  input_height=input_height, input_width=input_width  )
  File "C:\Users\rodgu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras_segmentation\models\pspnet.py", line 63, in _pspnet
    pooled = pool_block(  o , p  )
  File "C:\Users\rodgu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras_segmentation\models\pspnet.py", line 34, in pool_block
    pool_size = strides = [int(np.round( float(h) /  pool_factor)), int(np.round(  float(w )/  pool_factor))]
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Which is crazy, because I definitely have numpy installed. I ran the same code with a print(np.version.version) within and got: `1.17.3` (this also implies that numpy works everywhere except within the Keras function). I reinstalled numpy, and still nothing. I've been stuck here for days.

- I am using Python 3.7.5 and Windows 10.
- Also, [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921955/error-nameerror-name-np-is-not-defined) does not help.

Thank's a lot!

Comment: try updating the keras_segmentation, alternatively try using a virtualenv, and using a lower version of python (i.e. 3.6) and seeing if that works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aditya Shankar, I made it work. You must downgrade your python and then your tensorflow in order to use keras-segmentation package (at least, as far as I know). (Also, be sure to install any other dependencies listed in the setup.py file)

```
conda create -n lower_env pip python=3.6
conda activate lower_env
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
conda install -c anaconda keras
pip install tensorflow==1.4
conda install -c conda-forge shapely
pip install imgaug>=0.2.9
```